# SQL for finding recently trending items

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following data columns

```
date item
```

Every row is a transaction record of what item was bought on which date. How do I write a SQL to find the item that has gained most sales as a percentage over two time ranges. For example, to get at sales by items on a daily basis for a week, I can do

```
select
 date,
 item,
 count(*)
from table
date >= '2012-01-01'
date <= '2012-01-07'
group by 1,2 order by 1
```

If I change the date range for the next week, I can get the items that sold on that week.
But I want to find a SQL solution to get this done in one pull without having to manipulate the data in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
select item
     , 100 * count(*) / ( select count(*) 
                            from table 
                           where date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-07'
                                 ) as avrg 
  from table 
 where date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-07' 
 group by item 
 order by item
```

Answer (score 0):

I always get this backwards the first time, but something like the below might get you started.

```
SELECT d1.item, COUNT(d1.item) / COUNT(d2.item) AS slope
FROM data AS d1
JOIN data AS d2 ON d2.item = d1.item
WHERE d1.date > '2012-01-01'
AND d2.date > '2012-01-07'
GROUP BY d1.item
ORDER BY COUNT(d1.item) / COUNT(d2.item) DESC
```